# Give Free Space from "Free Space" partition to a specific partition

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, spaces, hfs

After some issues with my internal disk, I moved my OS on an external drive which is split into :

```
 - (disk2s2) Macintosh HD (Apple_HFS): my operating system;
 - (disk2s5) Volume 1 (Apple_HFS): My data Storage
 - Free Space: A free space partition resulting in my messing up
```

[image: Partitions]
[image: partitions_2]

I want to give the free space (550 GB) to Volume 1 (my data storage) but the command "resizeVolume" only allows me to give the free space to "Machintosh HD" (my OS) and not to "Volume1".

[image: limits for resizing]

The issue is that since my partitions are in Apple_HFS formats and not in APFS format, I cannot use the "resizeContainer" command as suggested in other posts.

I don't want to lose any data on both partitions.

How should I do it?

Comment: That's the kind of task I'd give to [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) - but I'm sure someone on here will know how to do it the 'hard' way, from terminal. Wish you luck. ;)

Comment: You can't expand partitions to lower block number with system tools. Since the free space is between disk2s2 and disk2s5, resizing disk2s5 would require to expand it to lower block numbers. Instead simply create a new partition/volume (550 GB) in the free space and copy the content of Volume1 (apparently ~273 GB) to it. Then remove Volume1 and expand the newly created partition/volume.

Comment: Seems like a good solution but I could not find a a command which would specifically target the freespace in order to create a new partition... Any hint ?

Comment: Does this help? [Create new partition in unallocated space with diskutil](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63130/create-new-partition-in-unallocated-space-with-diskutil)